# Python Regex exclude certain prefix

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Given the following string

```
s = '"foo" "bar2baz_foo" foo( bar2baz_foo( p_foo p_foo.'
```

I need a regex such that

```
re.findall(regex, s)
```

gives

```
['foo', 'bar2baz_foo', 'foo', 'bar2baz_foo']
```

So it matches the first four "words" excluding the quotes and parentheses but not the last two.
I have tried a couple different things but nothing I can come up with actually works.

Hope someone here can help.

Edit: I should add that I want to replace the results with something else and not just find it, i.e. I wanna use `re.sub` and not `re.findall`. And also the string is the content of a text file in reality and therefore much longer. I just extracted the relevant bits.

Comment: You should include the regexes/relevant code that you've tried in your problem description as well.

Comment: The `first four` or `not sartswith p_` ?

Comment: I my case it's the same but I think `not startswith p_` is better since more general. And I would add the expressions that I tried but they did not even get close to what I want.

Comment: Does it really have to be a pure regex solution?

Comment: Not necessarily. But since I am a total regex beginner I thought there was a straight forward solution that I just cannot come up with. I am using regex to replace text which is much nicer with regex than doing it by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not hell-bent on a pure regex solution, you could use [The Greatest Regex Trick Ever](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html).

```
>>> s = '"foo" "bar2baz_foo" foo( bar2baz_foo( p_foo p_foo.'
>>> import re
>>> filter(None, re.findall(r'p_\w*|(\w+)', s))
['foo', 'bar2baz_foo', 'foo', 'bar2baz_foo']
```

Small demo for usage in `re.sub`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'p_\w*|(\w+)', lambda m: 'WORD' if m.group(1) else m.group(), s)
'"WORD" "WORD" WORD( WORD( p_foo p_foo.'
```

Comment: This would actually work but since I'm trying to replace the words with something else it would also result in another 15 or so lines of code instead of one. So I would like to wait and see if someone else can come up with a pure regex solution.

Comment: @Lxndr Have a look at the `re.sub` example I just added.

Comment: I will post another question, but I can only post a question once every 90 min, so I will have to wait another 60 min. The problem is that the real string is actually the content of a C++ code file. So I would have to loop through the file in order to use the result of the `filter`.

Comment: @Lxndr Can't you do something like what I did in my `re.sub` demo?